# CSS Table left columns get cut off on smaller screen sizes

Tags: css, html-table

I created a code sandbox to recreate my problem [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-sinoussi-8zysbi?file=/src/App.js).

This is the table when there is enough room to display all of the columns:
[image]

This is the table when there isn't enough room for the full width:
[image]

You can scroll right to get to spell slots 8 and 9, but class levels and proficiency bonus are cut off on the left side. I'd like to keep those columns from getting cut out. What can I do to fix it so that all of the columns are able to be scrolled to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out one way of doing it.

First, I made the form have `position: relative`.

Then, I gave `.levels` `left: 20rem`.

Finally, I made a bunch of media queries to apply the fix at other screen sizes:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 512px) {
    .levels {
        left: 15rem;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .levels {
        left: 10rem;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .levels {
        left: 4rem;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    .levels {
        left: 11rem;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1536px) {
    .levels {
        left: 8.5rem;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1792px) {
    .levels {
        left: 4.6rem;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 2048px) {
    .levels {
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have a table with multiple columns and the table doesn't fit on the screen when the screen size is small, you can use the `table-responsive` class to make the table horizontally scrollable on small screens.

```
.table-responsive {
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Comment: I don't think I follow. What does the "table-responsive class" refer to? I didn't create a class with that name in my codesandbox and I don't see a css class in you answer.

Comment: Hi, sorry I add a table-responsive class CSS please check it now

Comment: obviously you are referring to some kind of css framework which has that class, but the OP didn't mention any css framework or similar, so your answer is really not useful.